# vue test utils error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

I'm new to vue test utils and I'm starting to implement tests in my app and regardless if I pass props or not I always get this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props').

Here is the component:

```
  <fragment>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <icon-link icon-name="fa-home" :link-text="$t('home')" to="/home" :big-icon="true" />
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-cases">
      <drop-down-menu nocaret>
        <icon-link slot="dropDownIcon" icon-name="fa-paste" :link-text="$t('my_cases')" big-icon has-dropdown />
        <my-cases-dropdown slot="dropDownContent" />
      </drop-down-menu>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <groups-header-item />
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <collections-menu-item />
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item alerts position-relative">
      <coin v-if="notificationCount" class="coin-alert position-absolute" :face-value="notificationCount" />
      <icon-link
        icon-name="fa-bell"
        :title="$t('my_alerts')"
        :link-text="$t('my_alerts')"
        :to="notificationsUrl"
        big-icon
      />
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <icon-link
        icon-name="fa-messages-question"
        :title="$t('help_uppercase')"
        :link-text="$t('help_uppercase')"
        :to="helpUrl"
        big-icon
      />
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <drop-down-menu right nocaret @shown="onShow">
        <icon-link
          slot="dropDownIcon"
          icon-name="fa-browser"
          :title="$t('apps')"
          :link-text="$t('apps')"
          big-icon
          has-dropdown
        />
        <apps-dropdown slot="dropDownContent" />
      </drop-down-menu>
    </li>
    <li v-if="$page.props.auth.isAdmin" class="nav-item">
      <drop-down-menu right nocaret @shown="onShow">
        <icon-link
          slot="dropDownIcon"
          icon-name="fa-cog"
          :title="$t('admin_settings')"
          :link-text="$t('admin_settings')"
          has-dropdown
          big-icon
        />
        <admin-dropdown slot="dropDownContent" />
      </drop-down-menu>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <drop-down-menu right nocaret>
        <icon-link :link-text="user.firstName" icon-name="fa-user" slot="dropDownIcon" has-dropdown big-icon>
          <template #icon>
            <avatar-image class="d-block mx-auto" :user="user" :size="32" />
          </template>
        </icon-link>
        <user-dropdown slot="dropDownContent" />
      </drop-down-menu>
    </li>
  </fragment>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  import ClickOutside from 'vue-click-outside';
  import uniqid from 'uniqid';

  export default {
    name: 'HeaderMainMenu',

    components: {
      CollectionsMenuItem: () => import('@/Molecules/CollectionsMenuItem'),
      DropdownIconButton: () => import('@/Atoms/DropdownIconButton'),
      MyCasesDropdown: () => import('@/Molecules/MyCasesDropdown'),
      AdminDropdown: () => import('@/Molecules/AdminDropdown'),
      DropDownMenu: () => import('@/Molecules/DropDownMenu'),
      UserDropdown: () => import('@/Molecules/UserDropdown'),
      AppsDropdown: () => import('@/Molecules/AppsDropdown'),
      GroupsHeaderItem: () => import('./GroupsHeaderItem'),
      AvatarImage: () => import('@/Atoms/AvatarImage'),
      IconLink: () => import('@/Atoms/IconLink'),
      Coin: () => import('@/Atoms/Coin'),
    },

    props: {
      linkText: String,
      appsDropdownId: {
        type: String,
        default: () => uniqid('dropdown-menu-'),
      },
    },

    directives: {
      ClickOutside,
    },

    data: () => ({
      appsDropdownOpen: false,
    }),

    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        user: (state) => state.currentUserResource,
      }),
      ...mapGetters(['repository']),

      verified() {
        return this.user && this.user.verified;
      },

      notificationCount() {
        return this.$page.props.auth.notificationCount;
      },

      notificationsUrl() {
        return this.$route('notifications');
      },

      helpUrl() {
        return this.$route('help-index');
      },
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['getRepositories']),

      onShow() {
        if (this.$store.state.repositories === null) {
          this.getRepositories();
        }
      },

      onAppsDropdownOutsideClick() {
        this.appsDropdownOpen = false;
        document.querySelector(`ul[aria-labelledby='${this.appsDropdownId}__BV_toggle_']`)?.classList.remove('show');
      },

      onAppsDropdownShow() {
        this.appsDropdownOpen = true;
        this.onShow();
      },

      onAppsDropdownHide() {
        this.appsDropdownOpen = false;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

This is the error I'm getting in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')



      at VueComponent.notificationCount (resources/js/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue:181:25)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
      at Watcher.evaluate (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3463:27)
      at Proxy.computedGetter (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5408:25)
      at Proxy.render (resources/js/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue:214:870)
      at VueComponent.Vue._render (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2561:28)
      at VueComponent.updateComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3785:27)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
      at new Watcher (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3352:51)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3802:5)
      at VueComponent.Object.<anonymous>.Vue.$mount (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8621:12)
      at init (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4309:19)
      at createComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6432:17)
      at createElm (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6386:13)
      at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6934:13)
      at VueComponent.Vue._update (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3680:25)
      at VueComponent.updateComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3785:16)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
      at new Watcher (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3352:51)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3802:5)
      at VueComponent.Object.<anonymous>.Vue.$mount (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8621:12)
      at mount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:14057:21)
      at shallowMount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:14083:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/Jest/HeaderMainMenu.spec.js:9:21)

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4504
    [Vue warn]: Invalid prop type: "nav-item" is not a constructor
    
    (found in <Root>)

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4504
    [Vue warn]: Invalid prop type: "nav-item" is not a constructor
    
    found in
    
    ---> <HeaderMainMenu>
           <Root>

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4504
    [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')"
    
    found in
    
    ---> <HeaderMainMenu>
           <Root>

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2922
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
        at VueComponent.notificationCount (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/resources/js/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue:181:25)
        at Watcher.get (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
        at Watcher.evaluate (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3463:27)
        at Proxy.computedGetter (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5408:25)
        at Proxy.render (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/resources/js/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue:214:870)
        at VueComponent.Vue._render (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2561:28)
        at VueComponent.updateComponent (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3785:27)
        at Watcher.get (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
        at new Watcher (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3352:51)
        at mountComponent (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3802:5)
        at VueComponent.Object.<anonymous>.Vue.$mount (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8621:12)
        at init (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4309:19)
        at createComponent (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6432:17)
        at createElm (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6386:13)
        at VueComponent.patch [as __patch__] (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:6934:13)
        at VueComponent.Vue._update (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3680:25)
        at VueComponent.updateComponent (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3785:16)
        at Watcher.get (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
        at new Watcher (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3352:51)
        at mountComponent (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3802:5)
        at VueComponent.Object.<anonymous>.Vue.$mount (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:8621:12)
        at mount (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:14057:21)
        at shallowMount (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.js:14083:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/tests/Jest/HeaderMainMenu.spec.js:9:21)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
        at /Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at /Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4504
    [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')"
    
    found in
    
    ---> <HeaderMainMenu>
           <Root>

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2922
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
        at VueComponent.notificationCount (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/resources/js/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue:181:25)
        at Watcher.get (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
        at Watcher.evaluate (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3463:27)
        at Proxy.computedGetter (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:5408:25)
        at Proxy.render (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/resources/js/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue:214:870)
        at VueComponent.Vue._render (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2561:28)
        at VueComponent.updateComponent (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3785:27)
        at Watcher.get (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3362:33)
        at Watcher.run (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3438:32)
        at flushSchedulerQueue (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4030:17)
        at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:3016:20)
        at flushCallbacks (/Users/ariana/Documents/cmrad/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:2938:18)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

And this is the test I'm trying to do:

```
import { shallowMount, config } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HeaderMainMenu from '@/Organisms/HeaderMainMenu.vue';
import DropDownMenu from '@/Molecules/DropDownMenu.vue';

config.mocks['$t'] = () => {};

describe('HeaderMainMenu.vue', () => {
  it('should render HeaderMainMenu items', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HeaderMainMenu, {
      props: {
        linkText: "$t('cmrad.apps')",
        appsDropdownId: {
          type: 'nav-item',
          default: () => jest.fn(),
        },
      },
      mocks: {
        $t: () => {},
      },
    });

    const dropDownMenu = wrapper.find(DropDownMenu);
    expect(dropDownMenu.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Can someone help me with the test? I'm also unsure how to test that all items are displaying.